# How to skip the first element of ls in for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I am executing a command which lakes list of files on my folder as input. So I am executing

```
cat <(for i in ls *chr*.txt; do echo $i; done)
```

However, I don't want to include the first entry from this list. In other words, I want to skip iteration   1, so I only have n-1 `*chr*.txt` files. How do I do this?

Comment: Do not ever use `ls` in this way. See [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Note that `echo $i` is also buggy -- it'll mangle filenames containing glob characters, runs of whitespace, etc. Always use `echo "$i"`, or even better, `printf '%s\n' "$i"`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/). Give more context. What's that name you're trying to skip? I bet we can fix it in the glob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't parse output of `ls`.

You can use this one liner:

```
for i in *chr*.txt; do ((first++)) && echo "$i"; done
```

Alternatively using an array:

```
# array holding matching files
arr=(*chr*.txt)

# loop through all but first file 
for i in "${arr[@]:1}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `ls` here at all. Put your files into an array, and you can expand the array starting at the second element.

```
files=( *chr*.txt )
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]:1}"
```

In baseline POSIX shells that don't support arrays, you can use `"$@"` for the same purpose, with `shift` removing the first item:

```
set -- *chr*.txt    # put all names matching the pattern in $1/$2/...
shift               # remove $1, putting $2 in its place, moving $3 to $2, etc
printf '%s\n' "$@"  # print each item from our argument list on a separate line.
```

Comment: @anubhava, heh, you're right. I was testing with `"$@"`, but `$0` makes that a special case.

Comment: @MAPK, one-liners are a bad idea in bash. Remember, this is a language with almost 50 years of legacy of backwards compatibility -- working around all the defaults that are mandated by bad decisions made by people implementing predecessor shells decades ago means paying a price in verbosity to get correctness. You can always put a `;` between your two commands if you really want them on one line for some reason.